# Find out which layout file is currently being displayed on the screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-view, setcontentview

I currently have an `AppCompatActivity` and I want to be able to switch its layout using one of the menu buttons I have set up.

I am able to do that currently using `setContentView`, however in order to then switch back to the original `View` displayed, I need to know which one is currently displayed.

How do I go about getting the current ID of the layout file being displayed?

This is what I have currently, the logic is okay but the code doesn't seem to work:

```
View currentLayout = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
int currentLayoutID = currentLayout.getId();
if (currentLayoutID == R.layout.two) {
    setContentView(R.layout.one);
} else if (currentLayoutID == R.layout.one) {
    setContentView(R.layout.two);
}
```

Comment: try to use isShown() method.

Comment: @Nikunj This only relates to visibility and unfortunately I am switching layout files, not playing with the visibility of views inside one layout file.

Comment: I think use `setContentView()` in that way is unadvised. You should use `fragments` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `findViewById` to find a particular view that exists only in the one which is currently. If `findViewById` doesn't return null, that means you were viewing that particular layout.

Answer (score 0):

You compare the Id of a view with the layout name:

```
int currentLayoutID = currentLayout.getId();
if (currentLayoutID == R.layout.two) {
```

I would introduce a simple class attribute which store the current chosen layout:

```
private static final int CUR_LAYOUT_ONE = 1;
private static final int CUR_LAYOUT_TWO = 2;
private int currentLayoutID;

// ....

if (currentLayoutID == CUR_LAYOUT_TWO) {
    setContentView(R.layout.one);
    currentLayoutID = CUR_LAYOUT_ONE;
} else if (currentLayoutID == R.layout.one) {
    setContentView(R.layout.two);
    currentLayoutID = CUR_LAYOUT_TWO;
}
```

Maybe you need some additional onSaveInstanceState()-behaviour. Depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (currentLayoutID == R.layout.two) {
    setContentView(R.layout.one);
} else if (currentLayoutID == R.layout.one) {
    setContentView(R.layout.two);
}
```

You are comparing the `id` to the `R.layout`. Those are two different entries in the `R` file. You need to compare the the actual Ids you've given your views. Usually you set them in the xml file.
For instance `R.id.layout1`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider using ViewSwitcher. This will be a lot faster then setContentView

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html

You just define ViewSwitcher as the parent of your views (you can switch between 2 views only) in xml like this:

```
<ViewSwitcher 
android:id="@+id/viewSwitcher"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

and you programatically switch between views like this:

```
switcher.setDisplayedChild(1);
```